# How to handle and normalize a dataframe with billions of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would need to analyze a dataframe on R (bash or even python if you have suggestions, but I don't know how to use python well). The dataframe has approximately 6 billion rows and 8 columns (control1, treaty1, control2, treaty2, control3, treaty3, control4, treaty4).

Since it is a file of almost 300Gb and 6 billion lines I cannot open it with R.
I would need to read the file line by line and remove the lines where there is even only a 0.

How could I do?

If I also needed to divide each value inside a column by a number, and put the result in a new dataframe equal to the starting one, how could I do?

Comment: Why do you think it is so large (300Gb)? When I make a data.frame of numeric values, I'm around 3.8Gb. Is there text involved?

Comment: You might look at the  `arrow` package, which has methods for doing analysis on larger-than-memory files, e.g. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/open_dataset.html

Comment: And in what format is the file saved?  CSV, JSON, XML, Free text, something else?

Comment: It's so large because row names are 25 character long strings. For each string I have the relative counts for each samples. It is a txt file and I would like to understand if there is a way to make it read line by line and delete the lines where there is even only a 0 (in order to start pruning the dataframe). I need to read it line by line because being so big I can't load it in full.